# XMLHttpRequest works fine on wifi but not on 3G

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app

Is it possible to do a XMLHttpRequest request using the mobile network (3G) ?

My code is working fine when the watch is connected to Wifi but when I disable it I got "0" for the XMLHttpRequest's status.

The watch is connected on 3G (Verizon) but not connected to a mobile (Bluetooth).

Am I missing a feature/privilege ?

Thanks !

Comment: Please tell us which tizen model are you targeting ?

Comment: I'm targeting a gear S2 and I'm using Tizen 2.3.1

Comment: You said your watch is connected on 3G, how? you are using e-sim?
Do other Internet based apps work in your gear?